# Failing make cloud-config.yml file in coreOS

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, coreos

There was not any cloud-config file in my coreOS, so I made one myself as below:

```
#cloud-config
hostname: coreos
ssh_authorized_keys:
    -ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAgU0+1JMi9jzAiHSTu9GL4eNX0KzP5E5lN/0dczRcLF+uX4NSO9DCUUIlkGDml70aXrIHhawfR/TSz1YEkJeZDwWyRKgNeqTGXax1HncLF9kHaWxn7At34qmfWdu54zvtfhZVOV2FKWMC0A8hizkFY+LPV8rkM1Hjoik2f8FZ491ucy8Lygrtd0ZWDPBp/EyqG90JwHF6lEZanhq/2vVPTJdJtLelpdr0Ouvw132r3ex7tm76nj+T10DOsGntNfNr/VD8Z1UD2sRxG9JgWgVHVjYzfy5ISCQwvbYG6DZG+e33SxZb5Ch9B5h8vCaRgsA1DX1K+rdp5fxCF5h1VkxaMQ== rsa-key-20151214
```

But it did not work when I tried to log in with putty through ssh key, also got error when logged in

" server refused our key "

and

" Failed Units: 1
  system-cloudinit@usr-share-oem-cloud\x2dconfig.yml.service "

Well I am confused about this cloud-config.

What should I do to make right one to work?

If anyone knows about coreOS, Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on what type of CoreOS system you are running.
Also, from your question it isn't clear how you tried to set your system's cloud config.

If this is a bare metal install (you used the coreos-install tool to install to a physical system), you should have a cloud config file at `/var/lib/coreos-install/user_data.`  `user_data` is your cloud config file here.  It should have been created from the cloud-config.yml that was provided when running coreos-install.

For most of the other types of systems (CDROM/USB, PXE, vmWare, etc.) the cloud config file is usually part of the environment and read during every boot.
You can find the locations of the cloud config file for other CoreOS system types [here](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cloud-config-locations.html).

If you didn't provide a cloud config during install, or in the environment you can use the following command to load a custom cloud config file:

```
sudo coreos-cloudinit --from-file=/home/core/cloud-config.yaml
```

of course you need to have command line access to do that.  just in case you don't have console access yet, you can [use the coreos.autologin Kernel parameter when you boot](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-with-iso.html#bypass-authentication) to skip login on the console.

Comment: I installed with CDROM with coreOS ISO, I couldn't find any cloud-config.yml, so I made one in /usr/share/oem/cloud-config.yml. maybe should I change location of cloud-config? When I tried to type cloudinit command, it looked like this: http://postimg.org/image/o7139f44t

Comment: CoreOS documentation says the location of cloud-config when installed with CDROM is /media/configdrive/openstack/latest/user_data. But I have nothing in media directory. so I made these directory and moved my cloud-config.yml to /media/configdrive/openstack/latest/user_data. and tried again to cloudinit, but it did not work. it showed the following result: http://postimg.org/image/uwdzxpjbd

Comment: When you install CoreOS with the ISO, you should be providing a cloud config file.  If you are using the coreos-install tool, the resulting installed cloud config file should be located at `/var/lib/coreos-install/user_data`

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your cloud-config at coreos.com/validate. I'm not sure that's what is failing here, but check it out if you keep running into issues.

Answer (score 0):

Validater suggests this works? but maybe it's 3 parts?

```
#cloud-config
hostname: coreos
ssh_authorized_keys: ["-ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAgU0+1JMi9jzAiHSTu9GL4eNX0KzP5E5lN/0dczRcLF+uX4NSO9DCUUIlkGDml70aXrIHhawfR/TSz1YEkJeZDwWyRKgNeqTGXax1HncLF9kHaWxn7At34qmfWdu54zvtfhZVOV2FKWMC0A8hizkFY+LPV8rkM1Hjoik2f8FZ491ucy8Lygrtd0ZWDPBp/EyqG90JwHF6lEZanhq/2vVPTJdJtLelpdr0Ouvw132r3ex7tm76nj+T10DOsGntNfNr/VD8Z1UD2sRxG9JgWgVHVjYzfy5ISCQwvbYG6DZG+e33SxZb5Ch9B5h8vCaRgsA1DX1K+rdp5fxCF5h1VkxaMQ== rsa-key-20151214"]
```